# Disk Manager is not showing correct HDD space

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, disk-management

My hard disk space is 500 GB. I recently installed Ubuntu 16.05 LTS on my system. Unfortunately I selected the option "Erase disk and install Ubuntu" while installing Ubuntu. After installation I checked my hard disk space, it was showing 150 GB as total space. After a while a decided to re install Windows 10 and checked my total disk space from 'Disk Management' window after installing Windows 10. It is showing as "Disk0 Basic 149.05 GB Online". What happened to my remaining 350 GB?

[image: See Image]

Comment: There should be an area after your C drive that states that it is either unknown, or unallocated.  Could you please post a screenshot of your Disk Management?

Comment: Screenshot added @Blerg

Comment: So far, I'm not sure what is going on with your partitioning as it should at least have the remainder of the disk as unallocated.  Try running the Ubuntu Live CD again and take a screenshot of the results from GParted.